# Create a set of macros to define a type called RETURN_STATUS and the following values:

Tags: c++, macros

I'm attempting to complete an O'reilly textbook on my own. I'm at a point where I really dont understand what's going on anymore. I read the chapters but simply dont know what to do when I get to the programming exercises. I know this problem looks like it should be easy but I have no idea.

The question:
Create a set of macros to define a type called RETURN_STATUS and the following values: RETURN_SUCCESS, RETURN_WARNING, and RETURN_ERROR. Define a macro, CHECK_RETURN_FATAL,,, that takes a RETURN_STATUS as its argument and returns true if you have a fatal
e r r o r.

my approach:

```
#include <iostream>

#define RETURN_STATUS RETURN_SUCCESS RETURN_WARNING RETURN_STATUS RETURN_ERROR
#define CHECK_RETURN_FATAL (RETURN_STATUS)

int main()
{
    if (RETURN_STATUS == RETURN_ERROR)
        return true;
    else
    return false;

    return 0;
}
```

This is just some BS I threw together hoping that a miracle would happen. I was wrong. An explanation of what I'm really supposed to do would be perfect. Thanks.

Comment: I think the first step would be to create a **type** `RETURN_STATUS` using a macro. The "following values" indicate (to me) that it's an `enum`.

Answer (score 3):

In C/C++ macro definitions consist of identifiers on the left side and stuff on the right side with which each occurrence of the macro is replaced in the body of your program. This mechanism is useful when you need to use a constant in multiple places (C++ provides better mechanisms for situations like that, but since your question asks about preprocessor, let's concentrate on it).

For example, you can define a type of `RETURN_STATUS` to be an `int`, like this:

```
#define RETURN_STATUS int
```

Now you can define the constants by choosing integer constants for their values, like this:

```
#define RETURN_SUCCESS 0
#define RETURN_WARNING 1
#define RETURN_ERROR 2
```

Finally, you can check the return status for error with this macro:

```
#define CHECK_RETURN_FATAL(s) (s == RETURN_ERROR)
```

Here is how you can use these definitions in a real code:

```
RETURN_STATUS check_password(const string& pwd) {
    if (pwd.size() == 0) return RETURN_ERROR;  // Empty passwords are not allowed
    if (pwd.size() < 8) return RETURN_WARNING; // Short passwords are bad
    return RETURN_SUCCESS;
}

...
string pwd("tiger");
RETURN_STATUS checkPwdStatus = check_password(pwd);
if (CHECK_RETURN_FATAL(checkPwdStatus)) {
    cerr << "Password check failed." << endl;
}
```

Comment: Does this `#define RETURN_STATUS int` "define a type"?

Comment: @DyP That's the best interpretation of the task from the book that I could come up with. Of course I'd never use this in production code: I'd go for an `enum`, or use `typedef`. However, this is a learning exercise, so I must assume that this is what they want students to do.

Comment: You could mentions this in your answer. I don't think it's neither a clear nor a good (as in "a good, useful, realistic") exercise..

Comment: @DyP so the question isn't a good question? is it even worth me stressing about how it's supposed to be done by the textbook's standards? Because I'm confused and I would love to skip this section if it's not going to be used later in life :)

Comment: @MauriceAbney Most people say, if you can avoid a macro, you should avoid it. Macros do have their place/usages though. You'll most certainly see some macros "later in life" so you should at least know the basics. I'd say this particular exercise is using macros in a way where they can be avoided => you can learn from this exercise how you **can** use macros, but not how you **should** use them IMO.

Comment: @MauriceAbney This is definitely a good exercise to understand, because there is a lot of code that uses macros. This is probably the simplest demonstration of what macros do, so it's worth doing simply to be able to read other people's code. I also agree with DyP that you should avoid using macros when you can avoid using them.

Answer (score 0):

I think a typical way is to return an error code, which is defined as enumerate type, for example:

```
enum ReturnStatus {
    SUCCESS = 0,
    WARNING, 
    ERROR
};
```

and then you can check return status using an inline function:

```
inline bool checkReturnFatal(const ReturnStatus status) {
    return status == ERROR;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I guess you either need a `typedef` or move the `ReturnStatus` before the `{`. atm, you're creating an anonymous `enum` and an object of that anonymous `enum` called `ReturnStatus`.